# Call AsyncTask from a spinner

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to call an AsyncTask from a spinner (depending on the option chosen will send something or other), but I get problems with a method I have in AsyncTask class and will not let me run it properly.

I'm getting the following error message:

> The method setOnResultsListener(OnTaskCompleted) in the type Conexion is not applicable for the arguments (new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){})

Comment: `I get problems with a method I have in AsyncTask class and will not let me run it properly` -- What does this phrase mean?  Are you getting an error message?  What is it?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, means that i cant run the app, i'm getting the following error message: The method setOnResultsListener(OnTaskCompleted) in the type Conexion is not applicable for the arguments (new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){})

Comment: You should post the code where you are trying to invoke/create `Connection`. The error that you're getting is because you need to call that like `setOnResultsListener(new OnTaskCompleted() { ... });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AsyncTask class, change this

```
public void setOnResultsListener(OnTaskCompleted listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

to this:

```
public Conexion(OnTaskCompleted listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

And in your MainActivity, change this

```
Conexion conexion = new Conexion();
conexion.setOnResultsListener(this);
conexion.execute("tipo");
```

to this:

```
new Conexion(MainActivity.this).execute("tipo");
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried,

```
     TextView item_clicked = (TextView) v; 
     String item_name = item_clicked.getText().toString(); 
     new Connection().execute(item_name);
```

This will pass your spinner data to the AsyncTask. Should be in your onItemSelected method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
conexion.setOnResultsListener(MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: I got this error message twice: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray. How I can fix it and it work the way I want?

Comment: I guess you are trying to convert html data to json, the text that you recieve from server is not json